# Difference between tomee 7 and apache-tomee-plume-1.7.6

Tags: apache-tomee

Initially i was using `Tomee 7.0.68` version to deploy and run the web application.
But I now onwards I need to use `Apache-tomee-plume-1.7.6` for the same. But after deploy what I found is that, **There is No *log* or *work* or extracted *war* files generated once I run the server**.

My question is, Is there any difference between apache-tomee-plume-1.7.6 and Tomee 7 to deploy and run/debug the appication?
How can I use Apache-tomee-plume-1.7.6 server?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

TomEE 7.x.x is compatible with Java EE7. 
TomEE 1.7.x is Java EE6 certified version.
Current TomEE 8.x branch is a work in progress for JavaEE8 compatibility.
As of today, TomEE 8.0.0-M3 is available containing also MicroProfile compatibility.

https://tomee.apache.org/download-ng.html